# How do I apply Tokens to a View?

Tags: 7, views

I have a list of car models from a database. I want to make a View that filters these by make, based on tokens. Eg for the token `[cars:make]`.

I already have the tokens setup, but would anyone know how to actually use these as filters in a View?

Comment: It's recommended to use taxonomy to categorize your cars by make. Then you can use the view to filter by tags/terms. Please explain why you want to wouldn't want to use taxonomy and how you created the tokens? If your tokens are based on fields in the content type, then you can filter your view by the fields I think.

Answer (score 1):

it may be posible with a node view, not with tokens, with field values: contextual filter, nid from url, provide a default value, php code, like:

> $node = menu_get_object();
>   if ($node->type == 'cars')
>   {
>          $mynodefiield = node_load($node->nid)->field_car_make[und][0][target_id];
>       return $mynodefield;
>   }

note: [target_id] is if field is an entity reference (node or taxonomy);

that view will return only nodetype=cars, and your token [cars:make] that have the same value as field_car_make.

sorry, i do not know how to do it with tokens, i hope it helps.